# Xamarin separate Service in different process problem

Tags: android, xamarin, foreground-service

I'm using this codes but I can't see Toast text never and there is no any exception. I want to run my Service in different process.

My Service class:

```
[Service(Name = "com.test", Enabled = true, Process = ":test", Label = "test")]
    class Seperate : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
        public override void OnStart(Intent intent, int startId)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "SERVICEEE", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "SERVICEEE", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "SERVICEEE", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
    }
```

And I'm trying to run with this code but it is not working; I can't see toast text never.

in MainActivity class, onCreate() method

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(Seperate));
            StartService(i);
```

Comment: What is the `adb log` output?

Comment: @SushiHangover now I am trying with an Activity, I can vibrate phone in different process but it is stopping to work after viration.

Answer (score 1):

About creating a Service that Runs in a Separate Process, the following properties of the ServiceAttribute that are important to an out-of-process service:

1. **Exported** – This property must be set to true to allow other applications to interact with the service. The default value of this property is false.
2. **Process** – This property must be set. It is used to specify the name of the process that the service will run in.
3. **IsolatedProcess** – This property will enable extra security, telling Android to run the service in an isolated sandbox with minimal permission to interact with the rest of the system.
4. **Permission** – It is possible to control client access to the service by specifying a permission that clients must request (and be granted).

To run a service its own process, the Process property on the ServiceAttribute must be set to the name of the service. To interact with outside applications, the Exported property should be set to true. If Exported is false, then only clients in the same APK (i.e. the same application) and running in the same process will be able to interact with the service.

More detailed info about creating a Service that Runs in a Separate Process, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/out-of-process-services#create-a-service-that-runs-in-a-separate-process